# Why are there two Phils?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-last-man-on-earth

I only watched the first few "Last Man on Earth", so I guess I missed quite a bit. So when I started watching again I was surprised that either there are 2 Phil Millers, or Tandy and Phil switched names.

What happened and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [this happened](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Last_Man_on_Earth_episodes#Season_1_.282015.29) in episode 11 of season 1:

> Phil starts changing his billboard messages from "Alive in Tucson" to "Moved to Tampa", but his ladder falls while he is working on his first sign, leaving him stranded. **A new, handsome man ([Boris Kodjoe](http://celeb-true.com/images/boris-kodjoe/boris-kodjoe-03.jpg)) arrives and rescues Phil, driving him home. To everyone's surprise, the new man is also named Phil Miller. Confusion over having two Phils results in a competition that the original Phil loses. As a result, he is now to be known by his middle name, "Tandy".**

Comment: Thanks. Will check off as soon as the timer permits. This has been bothering me throughout the second season.

Comment: You mean you never finished season 1? If so, yeah, you'll miss out on some stuff...

Comment: I kind of lost interest when they abandoned the original premise on such a large scale, but I started again. It's still kind of corny, but can be amusing, and I love Steenbergen.